# How to use GDI+ in C?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi+, gdi

Disclaimer: I'm only getting started in C, so it's likely that I'm missing something obvious, or not thinking the right way! :)

How exactly would I go about using GDI+ in pure C?
As I understand it, GDI+ has wrapped objects made for C++, but underneath it lies a flat API which is accessible through `gdiplusflat.h`, a C-friendly header.

My problem is that when I #include it, I get the following errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\gdiplusflat.h(30) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '__stdcall'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\gdiplusflat.h(31) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'brushMode'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\gdiplusflat.h(31) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'brushMode'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\gdiplusflat.h(31) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\gdiplusflat.h(31) : error C2059: syntax error : ','
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\gdiplusflat.h(31) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
and 100 more...
```

Now, I think these errors are due to `GpStatus` not being defined because peeking into `GdiPlusFlat.h` shows that all the functions are of the style:

```
// WINGDIAPI is #defined as __stdcall
GpStatus WINGDIPAPI
GdipCreatePath(GpFillMode brushMode, GpPath **path);
GpStatus WINGDIPAPI
GdipCreatePath2(GDIPCONST GpPointF*, GDIPCONST BYTE*, INT, GpFillMode,
                                    GpPath **path);
GpStatus WINGDIPAPI
GdipCreatePath2I(GDIPCONST GpPoint*, GDIPCONST BYTE*, INT, GpFillMode,
                                     GpPath **path);
etc...
```

The problem is that `GpStatus` is a typedef to `Status` in `GdiPlusGpStubs.h` (a C++ header), and `Status` is itself an enum defined in `GdiPlusTypes.h` (also a C++ header). I tried defining the enum myself, but for some reason the compiler wouldn't take it!

So... how does one exactly use GDI+ functions in C? Should I just load gdiplus.dll dynamically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that gdiplusflat.h really needs many more gdi*.h header files included before it.  But many of these header files that have the needed typedef declarations referenced by gdiplusflat.h also contain "class" declarations and other C++ keywords.  The C compiler will error out when it sees these lines.

You have two choices.

1. Simple.  Accept the fact that C++ is essentially a superset of C. Then just rename your ".c" file you are trying to compile to have a ".cpp" extension. Your C code will get compiled as C++, but that likely won't change a line of code you write.  Then #include gdiplus.h before you #include gdiplusflat.h
2. Harder.  depends on typedef definitions in other  header files.  The problem is that many of these header files have "class" definitions and C++ keywords that the C compiler will error out on.  You'll have to manually port over many of the C declarations into your own header file that gets included before gdiplusflat.h.  Here's my feeble attempt.  It's not quite done.  It gets half of the compilation errors out.  But I got too tired and just went with option #1.  You could finish it, but option 1 above is so much easier.

x

```
enum Status
{
    Ok = 0,
    GenericError = 1,
    InvalidParameter = 2,
    OutOfMemory = 3,
    ObjectBusy = 4,
    InsufficientBuffer = 5,
    NotImplemented = 6,
    Win32Error = 7,
    WrongState = 8,
    Aborted = 9,
    FileNotFound = 10,
    ValueOverflow = 11,
    AccessDenied = 12,
    UnknownImageFormat = 13,
    FontFamilyNotFound = 14,
    FontStyleNotFound = 15,
    NotTrueTypeFont = 16,
    UnsupportedGdiplusVersion = 17,
    GdiplusNotInitialized = 18,
    PropertyNotFound = 19,
    PropertyNotSupported = 20,
#if (GDIPVER >= 0x0110)
    ProfileNotFound = 21,
#endif //(GDIPVER >= 0x0110)
};



typedef Status GpStatus;

enum FillMode
{
    FillModeAlternate,        // 0
    FillModeWinding           // 1
};

typedef FillMode GpFillMode;

struct GpPath {};

typedef float REAL;

struct GpPointF
{
    REAL x;
    REAL y;
};

struct GpPoint
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
#include <gdiplusflat.h>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Flat API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from MSDN. There's a straight conversion from Flat API (C) to GDI+ (C++), I think it's fairly simple.

P.S: However you can still use GDI straight in C.