# Graphics::SetSmoothingMode in C WINAPI

Tags: windows, winapi, graphics, gdi

Is there any equivalent of Graphics::SetSmoothingMode from GDI+ in standard C WinAPI? I'm wondering if I can use anti-aliasing in my plain C code without rewriting the whole project to C++.

Comment: `GpStatus WINGDIPAPI
GdipSetSmoothingMode(GpGraphics *graphics, SmoothingMode smoothingMode);` declared in *gdiplusflat.h*

Comment: `GpGraphics *graphics` you can get via `GpStatus WINGDIPAPI
GdipCreateFromHDC(HDC hdc, GpGraphics **graphics);` or `GpStatus WINGDIPAPI
GdipCreateFromHWND(HWND hwnd, GpGraphics **graphics);` then call `GpStatus WINGDIPAPI
GdipDeleteGraphics(GpGraphics *graphics);` etc..  also in any case not need rewrite whole project - some files can use c++ and some c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GDI+ in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114591/how-to-use-gdi-in-c)